# Deleting Sheets from Excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all unnecessary sheets from an activeWorkbook, but Sheet1 because it will be my primary sheet with initial raw data in it. When I run the following code, my sheets gets deleted, but I get this error once it reaches my last remaining sheet. Run-time error '1004': A workbook must contain at least one visible worksheet. 
FYI: I am writing this macro in personal macro book so i can use it for all other excel spreadsheets.

```
Sub deleteSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      If Not ws Is Sheet1 Then ws.Delete
   Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't always a "Sheet1" in every workbook - are you trying to keep the first sheet in the collection?

Comment: @dwirony yes, the first sheet in the collection. Usually it will be Sheet1 since it's the default, correct?

Comment: Not always - if you make a new workbook, add a new sheet and delete the first one, then you'll only have a `Sheet2` in your workbook.

Comment: @dwirony Ahh- understood! so how should i go about fixing this error? assuming the name of my first sheet is "Sheet1" or the first sheet in collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> If Not ws Is Sheet1 Then ws.Delete
> ```

The Boolean expression `{object1} Is {object2}` evaluates *reference equality*: it will be `True` if `{object1}` is `{object2}`.

Here `ws` is a worksheet in `ActiveWorkbook`, and `Sheet1` is (presumably) a global identifier referring to the `CodeName` of a sheet that exists in `ThisWorkbook` - which may or may not be the currently active workbook.

If `ThisWorkbook` isn't the `ActiveWorkbook`, reference equality will fail for every single sheet, and that loop will attempt to delete them all, which is why you're getting that error.

Unless you want to delete sheets in `ThisWorkbook`, you can't use reference equality to make that check.

You can [go by `Index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55170495/1188513), or by name - in any case it's a good idea to ensure there's more than a single sheet in the workbook you're working with:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Assert ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1
    If Not ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then ws.Delete
Next
```

Verify that the sheet you mean to delete has the expected index (`1`) and/or the expected name; use the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R) and the Properties (F4) toolwindows for that. Bear in mind that the `(Name)` property is the sheet's `CodeName` identifier, which you can only use/access in the VBA project of `ThisWorkbook`; you'll want to verify its `Name` property - that's the user-modifiable "tab name" of the worksheet.

Comment: Must be a long day for you Mat :) haha

Comment: Great explanation! thank you very much! It worked :)

Comment: .... and there is the difficulty in deleting an item from a collection in a loop - hence we work backwards most of the time. But the fact that M_G hasn't implies some additional insight - would it work this time, or would it skip every second sheet?

Comment: @AJD See first bullet for [runtime semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/b132463a-fd25-4143-8fc7-a443930e0651) - the enumerator is only evaluated once, on entry: that's why modfying the collection as it's iterated makes no difference. Note that many other languages have different semantics for this kind of thing. Pretty sure doing that in C# throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim i as Integer
dim ws as Worksheet

For i = 2 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
   Sheets(2).Delete
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked, however this deleted the first sheet i am trying keep.

Comment: @KunjPatel does `Debug.Print Sheets(1).Name` output the name of the sheet you're expecting to keep? Are there hidden sheets before it?

Comment: You need to loop backwards since you're deleting sheets, no? `For i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count to 2 Step - 1`

Comment: @dwirony oh duh, the index will shift as sheets get removed from the collection! And that is (another reason) why you iterate object collections with a `For Each` loop.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon okay so it looks like excel uses stack to create new sheets, meaning new sheets will be on top of the old one. In this case, i am trying to keep the last sheet in my collection. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @KunjPatel then loop from `1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1`